# how to turn off / Disable Tab Change on Swype (import from react-native-elements) in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-elements

i am new in `react-native` and i am using this [react native tab elements](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/tab/) in my application like this

```
<Tab value={index} onChange={setIndex}>
  <Tab.Item title="recent" />
  <Tab.Item title="favorite" />
  <Tab.Item title="cart" />
</Tab>



<TabView value={index} onChange={setIndex} >
   <TabView.Item style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: '100%' }}>
     <Text h1>Recent</Text>
   </TabView.Item>
   <TabView.Item style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: '100%' }}>
     <Text h1>Favorite</Text>
   </TabView.Item>
   <TabView.Item style={{ backgroundColor: 'green', width: '100%' }}>
     <Text h1>Cart</Text>
    </TabView.Item>
</TabView>
```

but default `Tab Change On Swype` is active
how to `Disable` Swype Tab Change ?
i want only tab change while click on tab title how to do that ?

Comment: Is there any prop like _swipeEnabled_?

Comment: no..there are no any props for this swipeEnabled

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/discussions/3176

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
{(() => {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return <Text>Recent</Text>;
      case 1:
        return <Text>favourites</Text>;
      case 2:
        return <Text>Your Cart</Text>;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  })()}
```

Comment: Do you put this in `TabView.Item` ?

Answer (score 0):

They have added prop for this, you can use

```
<TabView disableSwipe={false} disableTransition={false}>
```

Refer:
https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/pull/3372

Answer (score -1):

Use `animationConfig` props to disable the swipe.

```
<TabView animationConfig={ toValue: 0 } >
//...
</TabView>
```

But I'll suggest you to use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You must use this property

```
<TabView swipeEnabled={false} />
```